# using css background-image:url(...) sometimes let's image be displayed when viewed only, why?

Tags: css, image

I'm confused on what makes background images that I set with css load when the image comes into view and sometimes not.  That is, I have one scenario in my code (I can give examples if that would help) where I can watch my network traffic and I don't see the image get loaded over the wire until it scrolled into view.  I had changed from using a standard img tag to the css background to make this happen.

Now, I have another simple example where I just have what seems to me to be the same

any guideline on when it gets loaded?

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand what you are asking. Examples would help.

Comment: Are you using any [lazy load](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=lazy+load+images&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=lazy+load&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0j69i59j0l3.6643j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) plugin in your website.

Comment: As @SheikhHeera said, your template is using Lazy Load, it's a technique where image is requested as and when user scrolls, thus it chops down http requests

Comment: Example Would be helpful, although you have to give images max 'Z-index' or you may try to preload images using JS. [preload here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: I tried using lazy load on my page. I realize I should have a way to use some kind of infinite list scrolling viewer, but for now I just need something simple that works.  I've got about 600 small images on the page that need to scroll into view.  When I tried that with lazy load both google and firefox hung while iterating through all the images.  Seems to me like 600 is not that crazy many.